# Need daily totals via web app date range query

Tags: google-analytics

Newbie Question!  I'm using the web api I'm able to get the entire totals over a date range, but I want the daily totals too!   Sounds simple enough, but I can't get it.  Trying

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:AAAAAAA&start-date=2013-09-20&end-date=2013-09-30&metrics=ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:bounces,ga:newVisits,ga:entrances,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:exits,ga:timeOnSite&query(start-date,end-date)&access_token=XXXXX

I can see in the console that I have data on more than one day during this range.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can add a "dimension" of ga:date (or week or year) that will return that granularity of detail to the queries.